# Compiling with GCC error: cc1 out of memory error

Tags: python, linux, gcc, compiler-errors, cross-platform

I have a machine running Xubuntu 64 bit and I'm trying to compile my pretty long C code. I am using `gcc`.

I chrooted in a raspbian stretch environment because the executable code must run on my Raspberry PI 3 model B+. To chroot I followed these instructions:

```sh
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
sudo apt-get install qemu qemu-user qemu-user-static
sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static /mnt/usr/bin/ 
sudo chroot /mnt
```

After get inside the raspbian environment I executed:

```sh
gcc -Os $(python3-config --cflags --ldflags) Code.c -o ExecutableCode
```

and got this output:

```
cc1: out of memory allocating 32324 bytes after a total of 543821824 bytes
```

The computational capabilities of my computer are pretty high (my PC is a workstation), therefore I do not believe that memory runs out. Does someone have ideas?

Comment: How big is `Code.c`? Perhaps you should break it up into multiple source files and link them.

Comment: The code is very long (some thousand of lines). I cannot split the code because I would like to hide the source code and I have just two big classes inside the code. @FredLarson

Answer (score 0):

You are running out either of *memory* or *disk storage*.

---

Try to inspect the output of

```
top
```

and see what is the memory consumpiton and the swap being used. If this turns out as the problem you can increase swap limits.

On the other hand, if memory consumption seems to be OK, you need to check your disk size

```
df -h
```

and see whether you are running out of storage.

---

In some rare cases, this error could be technically caused due to the lack of sufficient file permissions.

Comment: How could I increase the swap limit? @GiorgosMyrianthous

Comment: @Leo94 https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space

Comment: I cannot display the output of `top` inside a mounted file system. Anyway, could I increase the swap limit in there? @GiorgosMyrianthous